# How to prevent select from mysql while another proccess update row

Tags: mysql, laravel, locking

I have job dispatcher with laravel, each running job have selecting data from mysql and after got it update status field in db that row is in work.

But when multiple proccesses running it can be cross selected the same rows while it's not updated status.

tried `lockForUpdate()` - not helped, `DB::raw('LOCK TABLES accounts WRITE')` too

```
        $lock = Cache::lock('gettingWorker', 5);

        $lock->block(6, function () use ($acc) 
        {
            DB::raw('LOCK TABLES accounts WRITE');

            $this->worker = Accounts::getFreeAccount()->lockForUpdate()->firstOrFail();

            $this->worker->updateStatus('WORKING');

            $lock->release();
        });
```

laravel atomic locks seems not working too, just some `sleep(1)` working in this case, but it's not a deal - because thausands of jobs running every hour

Comment: Step 1: try to reserve non-reserved record `update table set who_processes=@my_pid where who_processes is null`, where @my_pid is identification number unique over all the system. Step 2: check does step 1 was successful (no one intercepted the reservation) `select count(*) from table where who_processes=@my_pid`. If 1 - everything ok, record reserved, may process, goto step 3. If 0 - some process interferes, goto step 1. Step 3: process record (update status and perform another actions).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use start transaction and select data using statement `SELECT FOR UPDATE`.